# file_get_contents from URL works on local server only

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I've just started learning PHP and working on a code which extracts public data from a Myfxbook page. Is there any possible answer why the following function runs great on my local XAMPP server and gives back the value I need but after uploading it to my shared hosting server it gives back 0?

```
function loadFromURL($url) {
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    $stats = $doc->getElementById("stats");

    $firstLi = $stats->childNodes[1];
    $secondSpan = $firstLi->childNodes[1];

    $strVal = $secondSpan->textContent;

    $roundGainPC = floatval($strVal);

    return round($roundGainPC);
}
```

What is more strange for me that the second function in my code works on both my localserver and on the shared web server as well:

```
function loadFromURL2($url) {
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    $stats = $doc->getElementById("historyTotalSpan");

    $strVal = $stats->textContent;

    $totalTrades = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $strVal);

    return round($totalTrades);
}
```

For this test project I'm using one of the public systems for both functions: https://www.myfxbook.com/members/autotrade/turtle-eur/1644166

Ideally the first function would return me the total gain which is currently 174 (rounded). Instead it returns 0 on the live server.

Comment: Make sure you have turned on `allow_url_fopen` on server

Comment: Thank you. I checked it and it was on. Also if it's relevant the PHP version on the server is 7.3.

Answer (score -1):

I think the function `file_get_contents` is sweet to get file from local drive
Use curl instead.

```
function loadFromURL($url) {
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
      $html = curl_exec($ch);
      $doc = new DOMDocument();
      $doc->loadHTML($html);
      ...
      curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Comment: Replace a simple one-line function call with this? Why?